# Change how hyperlinks are displayed

Tags: hyperref, color, pdf, cleveref, varioref

By using

```
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

one automatically gets hyperlinks in a red box

[image]

or a green box

[image].

Is it possible to change this? For example instead of boxing having the text directly colored in red

[image]

or green

[image] ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hyperref` has options to do this. See the documentation for details. For example, here's one of the configurations I use:

```
\hypersetup{%
        colorlinks=true,
        citecolor={green},
        linkcolor={red},
        urlcolor={blue}}
```